# Error loading a workbook with openxlsx in R

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to open an xlsx workbook that one of my colleague sent me with R.

But when try to load it using the `loadworkbook` function of the pkg `openxlsx`, it returns me the following error:

```
Error in fills[[fillId]]$fgColor : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Does anyone know where this error comes from?

Thanks

Pierryves

Comment: I would recommend the `xlsx` package. There you can use the `read.xlsx()` function which I have never had problems with...

Comment: I don't know where the error comes from but in my experience the XLConnect package is the best one around. Has always done the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

The xlsx package is the most reliable package to load workbooks in my opinion. I use it all the time.

```
library('xlsx')

data <- read.xlsx(file, worksheet number)
```

Thats going to be the easiest way to read a workbook into R.